# Energy saver 101 : sleeps after or when battery is at x hours?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, power-management

Using Mac OSX on a macbook pro. in energy saver - battery tab : if i have sleep at 1 hour, does that mean the computer will sleep after an hour on battery OR when there is a about an hour of battery remaining?

If its the former -> is there a way to make it the latter? I want the computer to sleep when battery has about half an hour left.

Can use terminal or preferences or put a well known freeware.

Answer (score 4):

It means the computer will sleep after an hour.
The computer (if it's a laptop) will automatically hibernate when the battery is very low (this is [hibernatemode 3](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)). Is that sufficient or do you really want the computer to sleep when there's 1 hour of battery left?

Comment: Thank you, and is there a way to change it so : the computer sleeps when battery has about half an hour left ?

Comment: @tgkprog, that seems like it could be kind of awkward if you were working on something at the point when the computer decides it has 1/2 hour battery left and then sleeps.